# Markers shows in wrong place - google maps -android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created android app where i show map. But unfortunately all the markers shows little lower than its actual position. I verified longitude and latitude and they are current ones.

I tried with

```
marker.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 + marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

this is my markers loading code

```
                 while (itr.hasNext()) {


            Business business = itr.next();

            point = new GeoPoint((int)(business.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int)(business.getLongitude() * 1E6));



            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
            LinearLayout markerLayout = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.map_loc_bubble, null);
            CustomItem overlayItem = new CustomItem(point, business, markerLayout,
                    getApplicationContext());

            CustomOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomOverlay(overlayItem.getDefaultMarker(),this);
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            mMapView.invalidate();

    }

    if (centerPoint != null) {
        mMapView.getController().setCenter(centerPoint);
        mMapView.getController().animateTo(centerPoint);
    }
}
```

but no luck

here is my overlay class

```
 class CustomOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<CustomItem> {


    public CustomOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }


    public CustomOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(CustomItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(CustomItem overlay, Drawable marker) {


        marker.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 + marker.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
        overlay.setMarker(marker);
            addOverlay(overlay);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use Projection to map your Overlay to your MapView

Comment: May I know how to use projection?

Answer (score 1):

Use Projection to map your Overlay to your MapView:
use it like follows

In your Overlay, Add this code to draw method:

```
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();


//GeoPoint class is your latitude, longitude.
GeoPoint point = //TODO assign long, lat

//This is your point on the map
Point myPoint = new Point();

projection.toPixels (point, myPoint);
```

Then you need some sort of a co-ordinate system to anchor. You can use:

```
// Mark some points through which to draw your circle, or you can do something else
 //This just draws circles of radius 5
RectF myShape = new RectF (myPoint.x-5, myPoint.y-5, myPoint.x+5, myPoint.y+5);

canvas.drawOval (mShape, paint);
```

Comment: after this where to use "myPoint" ? and where should i do above code? does it in Draw method?

Comment: //TODO assign long, lat -  u mean my FOR loop will come inside draw method?  i have 100 points which need to display as markers.